# Add product information to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I have a cart function that adds items to it, but I cannot get it to add the details of that item. Right now it just pulls generic data I would like it to get the product title, location and dates. I know there is a way to get to the text of the HTML, but don't know how to add it to this script. Here is the HTML mark up:

```js
var cartOpen = false;
var numberOfProducts = 0;
$('body').on('click', '.js-toggle-cart', toggleCart);
$('body').on('click', '.js-add-product', addProduct);
$('body').on('click', '.js-remove-product', removeProduct);

function toggleCart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (cartOpen) {
    closeCart();
    return;
  }
  openCart();
}

function openCart() {
  cartOpen = true;
  $('body').addClass('open');
}

function closeCart() {
  cartOpen = false;
  $('body').removeClass('open');
}

function addProduct(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  openCart();
  $('.js-cart-empty').addClass('hide');
  var product = $('.js-cart-product-template').html();
  $('.js-cart-products').prepend(product);
  numberOfProducts++;
}

function removeProduct(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  numberOfProducts--;
  $(this).closest('.js-cart-product').hide(250);
  if (numberOfProducts == 0) {
    $('.js-cart-empty').removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="cards-item">
  <figure class="card product">
    <div class="card-image card-image-2lc"></div>
    <figcaption class="card-content">
      <h1 class="card-title">McElroy</h1>
      <h2 class="card-title product__title">2LC Fusion Machine 1/2" CTS - 2" IPS Pipe</h2>
      <p class="card-text">The 2LC employs a semi-automatic locking cam (LC) system to maintain force during the cooling cycle. It incorporates McElroy's patented Centerline Guidance System and is designed to butt fuse tees, ells and other fittings.</p>
      <form action="" method="">
        <fieldset class="product">
          <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formitem col1">
              <label class="label req" for="pu-2lc">Pick Up Date</label>
              <input type="date" name="pu-2lc" id="pu-2lc/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class=" formrow ">
                <div class="formitem col1 ">
                  <label class="label req " for="rd-2lc ">Return Date</label>
                  <input type="date " name="rd-2lc " id="rd-2lc "/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="formrow ">
                <div class="formitem col1of2 ">
                  <label class="label " for="country ">Country</label>
                  <select name="country " id="country " x-autocompletetype="country-name ">
                    <option selected="selected ">please choose</option>
                    <option value="bkf ">Bakersfield</option>
                    <option value="ch ">Chico</option>
                    <option value="fsn ">Fresno</option>
                    <option value="hyw ">Hayward</option>
                    <option value="mtc ">Manteca</option>
                    <option value="oak ">Oakley</option>
                    <option value="rwc ">Redwood City</option>
                    <option value="sac ">Sacramento</option>
                    <option value="sal ">Salinas</option>
                    <option value="sj ">San Jose</option>
                    <option value="sjf ">San Jose Fusion</option>
                    <option value="sr ">Santa Rosa</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons ">
              <div class="back ">
                 <button class="primary button js-add-product " title="Add to cart " >Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
      <aside class="cart js-cart ">
  <div class="cart__header ">
    <h1 class="cart__title ">Shopping cart</h1>
    <p class="cart__text ">
      <a class="button button--light js-toggle-cart " href="# " title="Close cart ">
        Close cart
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart__products js-cart-products ">
    <p class="cart__empty js-cart-empty ">
      Add a product to your cart
    </p>
    <div class="cart__product js-cart-product-template ">
      <article class="js-cart-product ">
        <h1>Product title</h1>
        <p>Pick up Date</p>
        <p>Return Date</p>
        <p>Location</p>
        <p>
          <a class="js-remove-product " href="# " title="Delete product ">
            Delete product
          </a>
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart__footer ">
    <p class="cart__text ">
      <a class="button " href="# " title="Buy products ">
        Buy products
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the text of the product__title

```
$('.product__title').text()
```

This will get the country option selected text and value

```
$('#country option:selected').val()
$('#country option:selected').text()
```

This will get your dates

```
$('#pu-2lc').val()
```

Once you have the text, you can place it where you want. Just looking over the code it looks like you would want to grab these values within the 
addProduct() method. Please let me know if that is what you are looking for. I can provide more insight if we had the code for the cart its self.

Comment: That is what I would be looking for. Sorry, I completely forget to add the cart code. Currently I just put place holder items in there. I will edit the HTML snippet to have the cart as well.

Comment: @ james I updated the srcipt to have this line in it: $("h1").text(".product__title"), but that seems to just return the text in the field, not actually get the proper title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Nate,

First, I would add a class to the carts product title, targeting H1 could target multiple H1s on the page, but for now here is what you would do, 
var productTitle = $('.product__title').text();
$("h1").text(productTitle);

Comment: that does totally work, but it doubles up the h1 which I don't want. I have a feeeling it has to do with the prepend online the above. You and see it in action here: https://www.rbcompany.com/dev/rentals.html. The first item on the page is the one I have set up.

Comment: I was actually able to get this to work just needed to move around the placement in the script. But now I have the issue of when I added items, it just keeps grabbing the descriptions and dates and locations for each one and compiling them. How do I get it to add only the item that is selected?